# Google Maps: Overlay point not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

Hey guys hoping for a little help here.

**First I created a working map here:** http://leongaban.com/_stack/googlemaps/firstmap.html
Pointer is shown on the spot, however I needed to remove the Map | Satellite | Terrain buttons.

Digging a bit deeper I found an example here [disablingDefaults](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults). However I could not get the map to work using my google.map.js file and my API key. So I just used the script from [Google's example page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI).

**Now my 2nd map** I have the Map view options removed, but cannot get an overlay to show up :(
http://leongaban.com/_stack/googlemaps/

*Please Help!*

**Goals:**

- Use my Google maps API key
- Remove the Map view option buttons
- Put overlay pointer on the location.

---

Code for my first map with my google API 2 key:

```
<head>
    <title>Test Google Maps</title>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyAXsNu2EwRNqKJn9OmC19WPkEJFM0r6ALk&sensor=true"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {

            // var myOptions = {
            //     zoom: 16,
            //     center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.750159, -73.976473),
            //     disableDefaultUI: true,
            //     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            //   }

            // var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            // var point = new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);
            // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));

            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473), 13);
            map.setUIToDefault();

            var myGeographicCoordinates = new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473)
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(myGeographicCoordinates));

            // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(40.750159, -73.976473));


        }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 450px; height: 370px"></div>
</body>
```

UPDATED
**WORKING CODE! THANKS STACKERS!!!**

```
<head>
    <title>Test Google Maps</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.750159, -73.976473),
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var myGeographicCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:        map,
                position:   myGeographicCoordinates,
                title:      "My First Test Marker",
                visible:    true
            }); 
            }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 450px; height: 370px"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with how you define your latLng objects.

```
new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);
```

That was used with Google Maps Api v2. Now you're using the latest api(v3), and in new api, this is how you should do it:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);
```

EDIT: After your edit, i see there are some problems with the marker. In API v3  this is how you make a new marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:        map,
    position:   latLng
});
```

Following code sets a map, disables default UI, sets a marker and put it on the map;

```
function initialize() {
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.750159, -73.976473),
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 var myGeographicCoordinates = new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map:        map,
  position:   myGeographicCoordinates
 });
}
```

Comment: I just updated the code here: http://leongaban.com/_stack/googlemaps/ but still the overlay isn't showing up :(

Comment: Yes the point that actually shows where something is on the map, it also looks like an upside down tear drop.

Comment: Ok, it's technically an overlay but marker is a more common name for it. Anyway, see my edits. it should be what you want.

Comment: Ah I got it to work!, but I used a combination of yours and @Sean Mickey's answer

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have moved to the v3 API, you want to change your marker creation code from:

```
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(myGeographicCoordinates));
```

to:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:        map,
    position:   myGeographicCoordinates,
    title:      "My First Test Marker",
    visible:    true
});
```

If you want, you may also define a custom marker `icon` in the `MarkerOption`s that are passed to the marker constructor function and set the value equal to the path and name of an image file:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:        map,
    icon:       "images/my-nice-marker.png",
    position:   myGeographicCoordinates,
    title:      "My First Test Marker",
    visible:    true
});
```

Comment: If you are running the code as shown above, you're still using an old v2 class: `var myGeographicCoordinates = new GLatLng(40.750159, -73.976473);`. Change that line to: `var myGeographicCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng( 40.750159, -73.976473 );

Comment: Oh I was mistaken about the api, I had the right link. Thanks for the help!